# Java - Cómo crear una librería que tenga métodos que puedan afectar objetos tipo 'String' de tu proyecto?

Tags: java, poo, método

Es posible crear una librería en Java y al importarla a tu proyecto esta tenga métodos que puedan ser llamados desde cualquier objecto `String` y que la librería pueda obtener información del `String` que la llama? Algo como esto:

```
import paquete.libreria;

public class miproyecto{
   public Object metodoA(){

      String unString = "algo";
      // funcionalidades del metodoA.

      unString.metodoDeLaLiberia()
      // y metodoDeLaLiberia() pueda tener acceso al valor del String "algo"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no puedes hacer eso.

Por un lado, la **única** forma de añadir métodos a una clase es extendiéndola. De otra forma [la clase `String` está marcada como `final`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) y por tanto no se puede extender.

Sin embargo, nada te impide crear métodos estáticos que reciban como parámetro un objeto `String`, como hace la clase [`StringUtils` de Apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

Answer (score 0):

Podrías también **crear una superclase** como lo es la clase Object en Java, haciendo que todas las clases que definas hereden los métodos de la clase padre, pero tendrías que usar la palabra reservada **"extends"** para cada clase que desarrolles y **no sé si sería lo mas eficiente**.

Saludos